# window.location.reload(true) not reloading the page correctly

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have a PHP page which fetches data from a MYSQL database and generates HTML content based on rows returned from the database.

I am adding a new row in database on click of a button using AJAX, Jquery and PHP. After adding the new row, I am using `window.location.reload(true);` to reload the page. But the HTML elements corresponding to new row are not shown when I click the button. However, if I manually refresh the page using F5, the newly added content is shown.

Anyone knows why this could happen?

Below is the function which I call on click of a button. The page increaseCount.php updates database to increase the count of actors. But the HTML elements corresponding to new count are not shown until I refresh the page using F5.

```
        function increaseCountOfNewActor(characterName) {
            var actorName = document.getElementById("txt_actor_"+characterName).value;
            var actorImage = document.getElementById("img_actor_"+characterName).src;
            $.ajax( {
                url: "increaseCount.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    name: actorName,
                    image: actorImage,
                    character: characterName
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    alert("Vote received");
                }
            } );
            window.location.reload(true);
        }
```

Comment: compare apples with apples, not apples with oranges ... `window.location.reload(true);` is equivalent to `ctrl+f5` - updating a page content using `window.location.reload` seems to me a very unusual way of doing it - show some code

Comment: Could you show some code?

Comment: I have added some code. But this may not help much.

Comment: Can you try `location.reload();`? @TusharGarud

Comment: Tried. Also tried location.reload in many other ways, but did not work.

Comment: @ Jaromanda: ctrl+F5 is working fine but location.reload(true) is not working the same way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing ajax  with a complete page reload.

The `$.ajax` call by default is asynchronous (the first a from ajax...). Therefore it sends a request to `increasepostcount.php` and then immediatelly reloads the page - not waiting for `increasepostcount.php` to process the request. By the time you manually refresh the page, `increasepostcount.php` will have completed the processing of the ajax call, therefore its result are reflected on the page.

If you use ajax, you should not use page reloading. Use javascript to update that part of the page where these records are displayed based on the results returned by the ajax call.

Comment: Kudos! your observation was spot on.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be sure that the ajax call has done to do what you want, in your case "window.location.reload(true);" is running before the ajax response, due to asynchronous communication between Client and Server to avoid "freezing" on the screen and an unresponsive user experience.
You have to put your refresh code on Success ajax response or on done :

```
   function increaseCountOfNewActor(characterName) {
        var actorName = document.getElementById("txt_actor_"+characterName).value;
        var actorImage = document.getElementById("img_actor_"+characterName).src;
        $.ajax( {
            url: "increaseCount.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                name: actorName,
                image: actorImage,
                character: characterName
            },
            success: function( data ) {
                alert("Vote received");
                // to do here
               //window.location.reload(true);
            }
        } ).done(function () {
   // or to do here
    window.location.reload(true);
});
    }
```

Comment: Perfect! It's 2022 and this solution has worked perfectly for my situation, my scenario was the same error as the original post and adding the .done(function) portion to my ajax segment has resolved this issue perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

in your page `increaseCount.php` consider adding a header at the end.

For example:

```
if(isset($_POST['name'] && 
   isset($_POST["image"] &&
   isset($_POST["character"]) {
       /* do your stuff here */
       header("Location: /thePageYouWantToRefresh.php");
       exit;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @MoolsBytheway, but I already tried that

Comment: No, this is not the correct answer for this question.

Comment: The code in itself works, but it is not an answer for this question. If you have an ajax call, then 1) you do not need a redirect 2) redirects are actually executed by the client, which is the xmlhttprequest object instance used for the ajax call in this particular instance. The object will not have existed by the time it could process the header because the reload erases it.

Comment: i understand what u mean :) , i think i misunderstood the question !